# How to run .sh file on Ec2 Instance Start

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, server, sh

I am trying to run a start.sh file when I start my AWS EC2 instance. Currently I have to start the instance connect to it create a screen and start the start.sh file within it and disconnect.

I have tried putting the below code within the User data, which should run on start-up however when I connect to see if its working I can't see evidence of any screens active or the start.sh file running. I have looked in the /var/log/cloud-init.log but cannot see evidence of it trying to run (though I do not know what to look for)

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo su
cd
screen
sudo ./start.sh
```

The start.sh file is located in the root users default directory

Comment: The userdata script is run at launch, not every time the Linux instance starts. See [Run a Script on Startup in Linux](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/run-script-on-startup).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is using a cron job for this. Add your script to the cron file with:

```
crontab -e
```

add:

```
@reboot sh ./start.sh
```

with the @reboot  your job will be executed after startup.